# Conflict between package chemformula and cellspace?

Tags: tables, siunitx, chemformula

When the package `chemformula` is used I can't have a vertical space between the line and text as `cellspace` should do. If I don't use `chemformula` there is no problem.

Because I also use `siunitx` in the table I use `C{p{4cm}}` instead of `S`.

Is it a conflict between the packages? 
Do you have a solution?

Here is a MWE:

```
 \documentclass[english]{article}
  \usepackage{chemformula} %problem
 \usepackage{array}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{cellspace}
 \usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{babel}

\setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{12pt}
\setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{12pt}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{Caption caption}
        \label{Bla bla}
        {\footnotesize
            \begin{tabular}{|C{p{4cm}}|C{p{5cm}}|C{p{3cm}}|}
                    \hline 
                Categories & Categories & Categories \\ 
                \hline 
                \hline
                Blah blah & Blah blah & Blah blah \\ 
                \hline  
        \end{tabular} }
        \end{table}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! I have no problem whatsoever with this code. Are you sure you posted the minimal code reproducing the problem?

Comment: When i use this same code in Texstudio i have a problem... When the package chemformula is loaded i don't have space (12pt) between line and text. Try this same code by deleting chemformula package and observe the difference.

Comment: No difference for me. And it has nothing to do with TeXstudio, which is only an editor.  Do you have the problem with this very code?

Comment: Yes i use this very code as you can see on images...

Comment: Quite strange… Did you update  recently? Last version of cellspace dates back to last summer.

Comment: I am new on TeXstudio (last week) and don't know how to update only one package

Comment: @Mathilde you should never update just one package. Packages often depend on other packages and updating just one often enough breaks those dependencies. Always update the complete distribution (MiKTeX or TeX Live). BTW: I also have no problems with your code (TeX Live, updated yesterday)

Comment: Works for me with an up to date MikTeX. Can you add `\listfiles` to the very start of your `.tex` file and post the file versions you get in the `.log` file here?

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.1.26)  8 FEB 2018 17:02      Is It what you ask for ?

Comment: Yes – don't forget \listfiles.

Comment: I use the version 4.15e for chemformula package and 1.6 for cellspace package.

Comment: With the version 1.7 of cellspace it works.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is an out-of-date package. OP has confirmed that updating the package solves the problem.